# What is the integral $\;\displaystyle\int\left[x^2(x-2)\right]^{-2/3}\text{d}x\;$?

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the integral $\;\displaystyle\int\left[x^2(x-2)\right]^{-2/3}\text{d}x\;$?

I have tried solving this integral by using U-substitution and integration by parts but got nowhere. Don't really know what else to try. WolframAlpha gives an answer to the integral but is unable to show steps for the solution. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: $(x^{2(x-2)})^{-2/3}$ or $(x^2(x-2))^{-2/3}$?

Comment: @Math777 the latter.

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$ I = \int x^{-\frac43}(x-2)^{-\frac23}dx = \int \frac{1}{x(x-2)}\sqrt[3]{\frac{x-2}{x}} d x$$
Integrals of the form $$\int Q(x) \sqrt[n]{\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}}dx $$ where $Q$ is a rational function can be solved using the substitution
$$ t = \sqrt[n]{\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}} $$
In this case, we have
$$ t = \sqrt[3]{\frac{x-2}{x}}$$
that is
$$ x= \frac{2}{1-t^3}$$
It will transform the integral into an integral of a rational function.

Answer (score 1):

[Integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com) gives "steps". I copy below, but not sure if they are "useful"-

Problem:
$$
\int \frac{1}{\left((x-2) x^{2}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} d x
$$
Rewrite/simplify:
$$
=\int \frac{1}{(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}} x^{\frac{4}{3}}} \mathrm{~d} x 
$$ Substitute $u=\sqrt[3]{x} \longrightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{~d} x}=\frac{1}{3 x^{\frac{2}{3}}} \longrightarrow \mathrm{d} x=3 x^{\frac{2}{3}} \mathrm{~d}u$:
$$\tiny x=u^{3} \\
\tiny \frac1{x^{2/3}} =\frac1{u^2}\\
=3 \int \frac{1}{u^{2}\left(u^{3}-2\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \mathrm{~d} u
$$
Substitute $v=\frac{\sqrt[3]{u^{3}-2}}{u} \rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{~d} u}=\frac{u}{\left(u^{3}-2\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{u^{3}-2}}{u^{2}} \longrightarrow \mathrm{d} u=\frac{1}{\frac{u}{\left(u^{3}-2\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{u^{3}-2}}{u^{2}}} \cdot \mathrm{d}  v$
$$=\int \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{~d} v$$
(from here it is obvious so I stop)